# Changing a div's contents on mouseOver

Tags: javascript, jquery, hover, jquery-hover, mousehover

I have a couple of div's that have a paragraph of text inside as the contents. I want it so that when you hover over each div, it will change the contents from the one text to another. I know this can be accomplished with JavaScript (jquery?), but I have very limited experience with it, so some direction would be appreciated.

I have something like this:

```
div id="wrapper">
    <div id="div1">
    Here's the original text.
    </div>
</div>
```

I just want the "Here's the original text" in div1 to change to something else, like "Other text" when the mouse hovers over the wrapper, and to go back to the original text when the mouse leaves.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should get the job done. Not tested for cross-browser compatibility though.

```
var defaultText = document.getElementById('div1').innerHTML;

document.getElementById('div1').onmouseenter = function() {
    this.innerHTML = "some other text";
};

document.getElementById('div1').onmouseleave = function() {
    this.innerHTML = defaultText;
};
```

Comment: I think the OP was looking for a jQuery solution. Thus the million tags that he/she added germane to "jQuery".

Comment: @chrisjlee He does not explicitly exclude plain JavaScript but you're probably right. The jQuery variant is also preferable in terms of cross-browser compatibility.

Answer (score 2):

```
// store element to avoid overhead on each event
var $div1 = $('#div1');

// keep the current text
$div1.data('old_text', $div1.text());

$('#wrapper')
    .on('mouseenter', function() {
        $div1.text('Another text');
    })
    .on('mouseleave', function() {
        $div1.text($div1.data('old_text'));
    });
```

Here is a **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/h9datnub/)**.